# Compare and replace string in JSON using Groovy

Tags: json, string, groovy, substring, string-comparison

I would like to know how to replace the string inside JSON to another JSON.

```
 def old = '{"name" : "abc", "value": "123", "field" : "xyz"}'
 def neww = '{"name" : "abc", "value": "345" ,"field" : "xyz"}'

 def old_1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(old)
 def neww_1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(neww)

 def commons_slurp = old_1.intersect(neww_1)
 def difference_slurp = old_1.plus(neww_1)
 def final_slurp = difference_slurp.minus(commons_slurp)
 def replace_slurp = old.replace(final_slurp)

 print '\n' +  replace_slurp
```

and the final output is `{"name" : "abc", "345": "123", "field" : "xyz"}`

I want the to replace the old value with the new value.

AND, i need that the output would be `{"name" : "abc", "value": "345", "field" : "xyz"}`

Comment: If you struggle with the output of said merged map: `JsonOutput.toJson(old_1+neww_1)`

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier:

```
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(old_1+neww_1)
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'two outputs'? In groovy map1 + map2 == map1.plus(map2). Method .plus returns a new Map containing all entries from left and right, giving precedence to right.